# Dotpeek recompile decompiled files

Tags: .net-reflector, dotpeek

How i can recompile my edited codes 
Or replace it with original files and save it as exe in dotpeek ?

I try to recompile edited files and save it but i cant

If you found any way please share
Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Right click the opened file in Assembly Explorer pane and choose, Export to Project, this will save it as a Visual Studio Project that you can open and work towards compiling.

Comment: Hi, I tried to recompile the decompiled apps, but always encounter this error MSB3822: Non-string resources require the System.Resources.Extensions assembly at runtime. I found an online solution, but it doesnt resolve the issue.

what is possibly wrong? https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-tharp-7jyvdr?file=/file.csproj